# I'm trying to use elasticsearch aggregation generate array having sum of each element of array

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents that look like:

```
{
  "arr": [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
  "name": "test"
}
{
  "arr": [4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
  "name": "test"
}
{
  "arr": [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  "name": "test"
}
```

**I want to use an aggregation (or some other es method) to return:**

```
{
  "arr": [10, 7, 5, 3, 1]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch doesn't "properly" store lists; in your case internal representation of such field would be `arr = 5 AND arr = 4 AND ...`. Though if all docs have 5 items (or less) you can do something like:

```
{
  "arr": [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
  "arr_0": 5,
  "arr_1": 4,
  "arr_2": 3,
  "arr_3": 2,
  "arr_4": 1,
  "name": "test"
}
```

and then 5 `sum` aggregations over `arr_0` ... `arr_4`.

If there is no limit on the array length, you'll have to compute in your app I'm afraid.